# MySQL: Return X words before and after Y word

Tags: mysql, select

I've been trying this for a few days now and have been unable to get it working exactly as needed and no amount of searching has helped me.

In my database I have articles with links in them like so:

```
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen
 <a href="google.com>Google!</a> one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
```

What I want to be able to do is find the link within the article and report up to 5 words before and up to 5 words after (for example)

So my result would be something like:

```
ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen
 <a href="google.com>Google!</a> one two three four five
```

Can anyone help me with a query to accomplish this?

Comment: This is easier to do in a language such as PHP.  Do you have that option? Also, do you know the full text for <a href="google.com>Google!</a> in advance

Comment: Yes, eventually everything will go to PHP anyway.  Unfortunately the link text will always be different so...no I won't know it in advance :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SET @s = 'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen
 <a href="google.com>Google!</a> Albuquerque one two three four five six seven eight nine ten';
SELECT CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(LEFT(@s, INSTR(@s, '<a href="') -1), ' ', -6) -- 5 words before ' <a href="'
   , SUBSTRING(@s, INSTR(@s, '<a href="'), INSTR(@s, '</a>') - INSTR(@s, ' <a href="') + 3) -- the href
   , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(@s, INSTR(@s, '</a>') + 4, 10000), ' ', 6) -- 5 words after '</a>'
   );
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html for the docs.

This works for the first link in the string. BTW, I would do this in my presentation code (PHP in yr case), but it's surprising what you can do in the SQL. Make sure to check your input (WHERE quote LIKE '% <a href="%</a>%') because input with no link will probably not give you what you want.

Comment: if "body" is the column how would I populate @s with that information before hand? Would this be easier for me to pick up and read if it was in PHP? I'm a bit better with PHP than MySQL.

Comment: Simply use "body" in the places where I have "@s" and plug the whole CONCAT(...) into the query you're using now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that by default. Regexp only gives back boolean values, but if you use an external regexp plugin, [like this one](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp), it might be possible.